# Two assemblies with same name ,same version but different public key

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can two assemblies with same name,same version but different public key be exist in GAC ??

I am not sure this is valid point to ask or not but this what i had to face in one of my interview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: of course they can **exist** together in GAC. What you can't have is to use them both.

**Long answer**: assemblies are located in GAC using their *display name*. Two different assemblies with same name can be registered but only last registered one will be *visible* to applications.

In your case (different public key) you may have an exception if you referenced older assembly in your application: reference will be resolved to newer one but public key won't match then assembly won't load.

**EDIT**: this behavior doesn't come from assembly signing itself (signing is a first level weak security and a way to make an assembly unique), it's just how **GAC** is implemented. It's not even fixed on the stone, this behavior *may* even change in future. Nowadays just consider to avoid this weird scenario...

Comment: As I see in my `%windir%\assembly` also same name + same version + same public key can exist. (they have different language)

Comment: @codroipo absolutely, in to live together in GAC assemblies just need to have _something_ different (name, version, processor architecture, culture, public key).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [yes, it is possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_(CLI)) (emphasys mine):

> ***The public key token is used to make the assembly name unique***. Thus,
>   two strong named assemblies can have the same PE file name and yet the
>   CLI will recognize them as different assemblies. The Windows file
>   system (FAT32 and NTFS) only recognizes the PE file name, so two
>   assemblies with the same PE file name (but different culture, version
>   ***or public key token***) cannot exist in the same Windows folder. To solve
>   this issue the CLI introduces the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) that is
>   treated as a single folder by run-time, but is actually implemented
>   using nested file system folders.

Comment: Nit: GAC wasn't introduced to solve "that" problem per se, and has additional implications. The CLR *could* very well have employed GAC-like resolving using variations (or even allowed loading a strongly signed assembly via an explicit filename) .. instead GAC operates entirely differently, and happens to 'capture' the effect: strong-named assemblies in the GAC *are* the authoritative source.

Answer (score -1):

Yes they can, your assembly references can specify the public key of the assembly you want to reference, so they could have the same name, version, culture, anything really, as long as you specify the public key it'll know which you want to use.

Comment: No, if there are two assemblies with same name and different public key...you'll get an exception if you try to load _older_ one.

Comment: Really? I'll need to do some testing of that, I don't see why it wouldn't let you load the older one as long as you weren't trying to use both at once